# Is it possible to efficiently pass both bytes and bytearray objects to an external library using ctypes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

Suppose I have the following function in an external library:

```
void foo(const unsigned char *buf, const int len);
```

I would like to be able to call this function from my Python code, using `ctypes`, without making a copy of the buffer. The buffer could be quite large so avoiding a copy has obvious performance benefits. And for the convenience of the consumer of my code, I would like to be able to supply this buffer either as `bytes` or `bytearray`.

At the moment I declare `buf` as `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` in my `argtypes` declaration.

```
lib.foo.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_int]
buf = bytes(...)
lib.foo(buf, len(buf))
```

This works fine, and I can pass a `bytes` object. However, if I pass a `bytearray` object then I encounter the following error:

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : wrong type

Is there a way for me to allow `bytearray` to be passed, preferably interchangeably with `bytes`?

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for responding. I don't have any real cares about how this is achieved. I just would like for the external code to receive a `const unsigned char*` without copying the content of the buffer. If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subclass of the pointer type that overrides `from_param` to adapt a `bytearray`. For example:

```
class Pchar(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)):
    _type_ = ctypes.c_char
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, param, array_t=ctypes.c_char * 0):
        if isinstance(param, bytearray):
            param = array_t.from_buffer(param)
        return super(Pchar, cls).from_param(param)

lib.foo.argtypes = [Pchar, ctypes.c_int]
```

The `c_char` array that's created for the `bytearray` is only needed to get at the internal buffer of the object via Python's buffer protocol. The array size doesn't matter, so we can avoid creating an array subclass for every possible length of `bytearray`. Simply use a length 0 array type that's cached in the `from_param` argument list.

Comment: Thanks again Eryk, I really owe you a beer!

Comment: *cached in the from_param argument list*. I was interested by that. The classmethod defined in `ctypes._CData` has no `array_t` argument, right? It has just one argument, what you name param here. But you've added a named argument, `array_t`, that will never be provided by any caller. You do that so that the default value is evaluated at module load, which is a potentially time consuming act. That way you only pay that cost once. Is that correct? I've never come across this technique before!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I used the argument list to slightly optimize the lookup. I could have used a class attribute, which is slightly slower. I could also simply rely on how ctypes caches the type created by `ctypes.c_char * 0`. For the latter it would still have execute the byte code each time, call the `sq_repeat` function, and eventually call `PyCArrayType_from_ctype`, which returns the cache type based on the tuple key `(c_char, 0)`. That may seem like a lot, but it's relatively cheap compared to the cost of actually creating a new type object, which is why ctypes has type caches.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the trick of using default argument in the argument list for a speed hack would typically be labeled a premature optimization. Where this trick is more commonly used is in the `__del__` method and other functions and methods that can be called while the interpreter is being torn down -- especially in Python 2.